# Python Folium map with a FloatImage under LayerControl

Tags: python, html, folium

I thought let's stick a compass rose or any other graphic legend on a foliun map such that I can switch it on or off using the LayerControl button:

```
import folium 
from folium.plugins import FloatImage

map = folium.Map(location= (52.3, 4.76),
                 zoom_start=10,
                 min_zoom = 7,
                 max_zoom = 15
                 )
# throw in some possble background tiles
folium.TileLayer(tiles='OpenStreetMap', opacity=0.7).add_to(map)
folium.TileLayer(tiles='cartodbpositron', opacity=0.7).add_to(map)
folium.TileLayer(tiles='CartoDB dark_matter', opacity=0.7).add_to(map)

# add a legend diagram to map
compass_rose = folium.FeatureGroup('compass rose')
FloatImage('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/99/Compass_rose_simple.svg', bottom =80, left = 7).add_to(compass_rose)
compass_rose.add_to(map)

# add layercontrol
folium.LayerControl(position='topright', collapsed=False, autoZIndex=True, sortLayers=False).add_to(map)

display(map)
```

It does now include the graphic in the LayerControl button, but sadly though, this does not seem to work correct. The graphic is there always, regardless of the switch state of LayerControl.
Any clues how I can get this to work?
(and any clues how I can show the HTML here?)